# Use a loop to generate a list for another (foreach) loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, programming, loops

Is it possible to use a loop to generate a list for a foreach loop? More specifically I want the following:

Consider the following answer to a question I asked some time ago: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38793/4011

It worked very well except if I define `\alist` as follows:

```
\def\alist{
    \foreach \i in {1,2,3}{
      \i/1,
      }4/1
    }
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Undefined control sequence.

--- TeX said ---
\foreach ...reach \let \pgffor@assign@before@code 
                                                  =\pgfutil@empty \let \pgff...
l.38   \rectDiv{7}{5}{(1,1)}{(4,3)}{\alist}
```

Is there any way to fix this?

**Edit**:

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
  \def\rectDiv#1#2#3#4#5{%#columns, #rows, rectangle start, rectangle end, list of elements to fill
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw #3 rectangle #4;
      \path #3;
      \pgfgetlastxy{\firstx}{\firsty}
      \path #4;
      \pgfgetlastxy{\secondx}{\secondy}
      \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\xdiff}{\secondx-\firstx}
      \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\ydiff}{\secondy-\firsty}
      \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\myxstep}{\xdiff/#1}
      \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\myystep}{\ydiff/#2}
      \foreach \x in {1,...,#1}{
        \draw ($#3 +\x*(\myxstep,0)$) -- ($#3 +(0,\ydiff) +\x*(\myxstep,0)$);
      }
      \foreach \y in {1,...,#2}{
        \draw ($#3 +\y*(0,\myystep)$) -- ($#3 +(\xdiff,0) +\y*(0,\myystep)$);
      }
      \edef\temp{\noexpand\foreach \noexpand\i/\noexpand\j in {#5}}
      \temp{
        \path[fill=blue!20,draw] ($#3 + (\i*\myxstep,\j*\myystep)$) rectangle ($#3 + (\i*\myxstep,\j*\myystep) + (\myxstep,\myystep)$);
      }
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\begin{document}
  \rectDiv{7}{5}{(1,1)}{(4,3)}{0/0,1/1,2/0,5/3}

  \def\list{1/0}
  \rectDiv{7}{5}{(1,1)}{(4,3)}{\list}

  \rectDiv{7}{5}{(1,1)}{(4,3)}{\list,2/0,5/3}

  \def\alist{
    \foreach \i in {1,2,3}{
      \i/1,
      }4/1
    }

   \alist

   \rectDiv{7}{5}{(1,1)}{(4,3)}{\alist}  %this doesn't  work

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is that you wrote

```
\edef\temp{\noexpand\foreach \noexpand\i/\noexpand\j in {#5}}

% Here is what #5 is in \temp:
\def\alist{
\foreach \i in {1,2,3}{
  \i/1,
  }4/1
}
```

which requires that the stuff in the braces be "fully expandable".  Alas, `\foreach` is not expandable, and it is part of `\alist`.  So when `\temp` is defined, it expands "as much as possible" and hits some non-expandable part of the code of `\foreach`, which in this case is `\let \pgffor@assign@before@code = ...`; `\let` is an *assignment*, and not expandable, so is not changed by `\edef`.  Thus, the assignment is not actually performed, and `\edef` goes on to try to interpret the following control sequence `\pgffor@assign@before@code` directly.  Not surprisingly, it is not defined, since it was the `\let` that is supposed to define it, so you get an error.

To do this, you have to create a macro that contains the *output* of `\alist`.  For example,

```
\gdef\alist{}
\foreach \i in {1,2,3} {
 \xdef\alist{\alist \i/1,}
}
\xdef\alist{\alist 4/1}
```

Then you can use `\alist` directly instead of `\temp.` (I have used global assignments for `\alist` because `\foreach` executes its contents in a group.)

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using global macros?

Comment: Not with `\foreach`. It acts in a group, so you have to break out with global macros.