# How to access whether a node is "on grid" or not

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like access the variable that stores `on grid` option is activated or not, to calculate a few distances in my `\pgfdeclareshape`.

I did some research. I read [How to extract the value from a pgfkeys style element](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41660/how-to-extract-the-value-from-a-pgfkeys-style-element) and [Accessing a style property in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49923/accessing-a-style-property-in-tik)
. Then, I guess that the value of `on grid` is stored in `tikz@lib@ignore@size`. I tried to extract the value by an idea addressed in [Accessing a style property in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49923/accessing-a-style-property-in-tik) .

My MWE is as below:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\makeatletter
\def\getongrid{\tikz@lib@ignore@size}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3mm]
  \node [] (n1) {1};
  \node [right=of n1] (n2) {\getongrid};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**But I got an error:**

```
Undefined control sequence.
\getongrid ->\tikz@lib@ignore@size 

l.17   \node [right=of n1] (n2) {\getongrid
                                           };
```

**How can I fix this?**

For your information, I got the following trace by `trace-pgfkeys.sty`.

```
[trace-pgfkeys]-+ \pgfkeysdefaultpath : /tikz
[trace-pgfkeys]-+ Key/value list: (on grid/.is if=tikz@lib@ignore@size)
[trace-pgfkeys]-+ Current key-value: (#1)
[trace-pgfkeys]-+ \pgfkeyscurrentkey (given): on grid/.is if
[trace-pgfkeys]-> \pgfkeyscurrentkey : /tikz/on grid/.is if
[trace-pgfkeys]-+ \pgfkeyscurrentvalue : (tikz@lib@ignore@size)
[trace-pgfkeys]-+ \pgfkeyscurrentpath (/tikz/on grid)
[trace-pgfkeys]-+ \pgfkeyscurrentname (.is if)
[trace-pgfkeys]-+ Executing all handlers.
[trace-pgfkeys]--+ Executing handler.
[trace-pgfkeys]--> Handler: /handlers/.is if
[trace-pgfkeys]--+ \pgfkeysdefaultpath : (/tikz/)
[trace-pgfkeys]--+ Key/value list: (\pgfkeyscurrentpath /.code=\pgfkeys@handle@
boolean {tikz@lib@ignore@size}{##1}, \pgfkeyscurrentpath /.default=true)
[trace-pgfkeys]---+ Current key-value: (#1)
[trace-pgfkeys]---+ \pgfkeyscurrentkey (given): /tikz/on grid/.code
[trace-pgfkeys]---> \pgfkeyscurrentkey : /tikz/on grid/.code
[trace-pgfkeys]---+ \pgfkeyscurrentvalue : (\pgfkeys@handle@boolean {tikz@lib@i
gnore@size}{##1})
[trace-pgfkeys]---+ \pgfkeyscurrentpath (/tikz/on grid)
[trace-pgfkeys]---+ \pgfkeyscurrentname (.code)
[trace-pgfkeys]---+ Executing all handlers.
[trace-pgfkeys]----+ Executing handler.
[trace-pgfkeys]----> Handler: /handlers/.code
[trace-pgfkeys]----+ Execution finished.
[trace-pgfkeys]---+ Current key-value: (#1)
[trace-pgfkeys]---+ \pgfkeyscurrentkey (given): /tikz/on grid/.default
[trace-pgfkeys]---> \pgfkeyscurrentkey : /tikz/on grid/.default
[trace-pgfkeys]---+ \pgfkeyscurrentvalue : (true)
[trace-pgfkeys]---+ \pgfkeyscurrentpath (/tikz/on grid)
[trace-pgfkeys]---+ \pgfkeyscurrentname (.default)
[trace-pgfkeys]---+ Executing all handlers.
[trace-pgfkeys]----+ Executing handler.
[trace-pgfkeys]----> Handler: /handlers/.default
[trace-pgfkeys]----+ Execution finished.
[trace-pgfkeys]---+ Last key processed.
[trace-pgfkeys]--+ Execution finished.
[trace-pgfkeys]-+ Last key processed.
```

Comment: you shouldn't be doing anything based on that actually. What do you have in mind ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The internal variable is an `\if...` switch:

```
\iftikz@lib@ignore@size <true case> \else <false case> \fi
```

Example file:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\makeatletter
\def\getongrid{\iftikz@lib@ignore@size true\else false\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3mm]
  \node [] (n1) {1};
  \node [right=of n1] (n2) {\getongrid};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]