# how to see content of a tikz style?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, debugging

I'm creating a tikz style to do some complicated linear transformation on the coordinates, computed in terms of variables. To give an idea, here's what the style declaration looks like now:

```
\tikzset{foo/.style={cm={\cosLgP,
                         \sinLgP * (-\sinEl),
                         \cosLa * \cosLg,
                         \sinLa * \cosEl - \cosLa * \sinLg * \sinEl,     
                         (0,0)}}}
```

...where `\cosLgP` &co are some previously defined macros (that should evaluate to various sines and cosines, if all goes well).

There's a bug and the coordinate transformation appears to be incorrect. How do I debug? Specifically, how do I print the (numerical) contents of the transformation matrix of `foo`, to see what it ended up containing?

Thanks!

Comment: Related I think: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41660/how-to-extract-the-value-from-a-pgfkeys-style-element

Comment: inside `foo/.style` add `/utils/exec={\show\cosLgP}` (mind the initial forward slash) as the last item. If those values are dimen registers then use `\showthe` instead

Comment: @percusse: Thanks! I noticed this command works anywhere and one can also do `/utils/exec={\show\cosLgP\show\sinLa}` and it works as expected. Only drawback I guess is that it interrupts the LaTeXing process, instead of "dumping" the values somewhere for later inspection.

Comment: @Labrador You can try `\typeout{\cosLgP}` (instead of `\show\cosLgP`) to show the value in your `.log` file without interruption...

Answer (score 1):

inside `foo/.style` add `/utils/exec={\show\cosLgP}` (mind the initial forward slash) as the last item. If those values are dimen registers then use `\showthe` instead.

Alternatively instead of `show`ing you can dump them into macros inside `utils/exec` and check their values afterwards

Answer (score 1):

*I answer the initial question: how to see content of a tikz style?*

You can try the `.show code` handler (p.893, pgfmanual) to show the definition of a style but with interruption during compilation.

In the following document, I define the new handler `.typeout code` to put the definition of a style in the `.log` file:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
% handler to use \typeout instead of \show (based on code of '.show code' handler)
\pgfkeys{
  /handlers/.typeout code/.code={%
    \pgfkeysgetvalue{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@cmd}{\pgfkeysshower}%
    \typeout{--- \pgfkeyscurrentpath\space---}%
    \typeout{\meaning\pgfkeysshower}%
  }
}
% application to your style
\tikzset{
  foo/.style={cm={\cosLgP,
      \sinLgP * (-\sinEl),
      \cosLa * \cosLg,
      \sinLa * \cosEl - \cosLa * \sinLg * \sinEl,     
      (0,0)}},
  foo/.typeout code,
}
% application to an ".estyle":
\def\cosLgP{1} \def\sinLgP{0}
\def\cosEl{0.707} \def\sinEl{0.707}
\def\cosLa{.848} \def\sinLa{.529}
\def\cosLg{0} \def\sinLg{1}
\tikzset{
  efoo/.estyle={cm={\cosLgP,
      \sinLgP * (-\sinEl),
      \cosLa * \cosLg,
      \sinLa * \cosEl - \cosLa * \sinLg * \sinEl,     
      (0,0)}},
  efoo/.typeout code,
}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

In the `.log` file:

```
--- /tikz/foo ---
\long macro:#1\pgfeov ->\pgfkeysalso {cm={\cosLgP , \sinLgP * (-\sinEl ), \cosLa * \cosLg , \sinLa * \cosEl - \cosLa * \sinLg * \sinEl , (0,0)}}
--- /tikz/efoo ---
\long macro:#1\pgfeov ->\pgfkeysalso {cm={1, 0* (-0.707), .848* 0, .529* 0.707- .848* 1* 0.707, (0,0)}}
```